# Can you have a time without a date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to import some data in from a flat file and am getting some odd results. When importing a time that is unattached to a date, why do I get a date inserted into this time as well?

```
1.9.3-p286 :008 > v.arrival_time = Time.parse("10:10")
 => 2012-11-06 10:10:00 -0400
```

I'm guessing that there is only a way to keep the date by itself, but no way to keep the time by itself despite the active record column-type :time. Is there a way to keep them separate such as:

```
1.9.3-p286 :002 > Date.parse("JAN 01 2000")
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000
```

Comment: you can use strftime but the output is a String object: 
`puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") # => "09:33:00 -0400"` OR 
`puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %Z %z") # => "09:33:00 EDT -0400"`

Comment: I've run in to this issue as well, and I've just written code to convert the time string you're getting in to an integer value of the number of seconds. Doing the string manipulation is pretty easy, even more so if you know it's always in the form HH:MM.

Comment: If all data conforms to the format `"10:10"` you could also consider saving the hours and minutes. `v.arrival_hour, v.arrival_minute = '10:10'.split(':').map(&method(:Integer))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html) object in Ruby uses "[Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)" to store temporal points as seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.  Various methods such as [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) merely change the format of the output, but not how the object is stored internally.

So you have a decision to make:  keep your imported data as a Time object, and be mindful of what it actually contains, or import your data as a string but forgo all the lovely, useful features of `Time`.

Answer (score 10):

There's this gem `tod`, `TimeOfDay` which provides functionality like that.

https://github.com/JackC/tod